# Problem during animation preview on linux

Tags: animation

I have done a simple animation but every time inside the preview it is laggy or sometimes it does not show anything. I have tried another blender version but I had the same problem, I'm using Linux Elementary OS

I made a video so you can see by yourself: [Youtube video](https://youtu.be/aVDTWYaUZ9k)